# Azure Timer Based Function Running concurrently Issue

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions

I am developing an Azure timer trigger-based function. I want to run it for each 1 min. It's running but it runs a new instance again in the middle of the current function execution (not completed fully). How to make sure only 1 instance should run and after it ends then only the next execution should start (even though the trigger is 1 min)?

Comment: How long does a run take?

Comment: Is it locally or on Azure Portal? Can you provide the Function Invocation traces.

Comment: yes its locally now.  i have set 1 min schedule.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Xhj3cNz.png - I'm not getting the new instance for 1 min schedule. Could you please recheck by clean and rebuild or provide the cron schedule expression so that it would be helpful to see the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

As I have checked the Azure Functions Timer Trigger, I'm not getting the new instance for 1 min schedule.

A timer-triggered function is only called once across all instances if a function app [scales out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp#scale-out) to include more than one instance. If there is still an active pending invocation, it won't trigger once again.

> How to make sure only 1 instance should run and after it ends then only the next execution should start (even though the trigger is 1 min)?

Basically, this Timer Trigger Function runs on [Singleton Lock](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/wiki/TimerTrigger#singleton-locks) feature, it ensures that only 1 instance is running.

Refer to this [GitHub issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/45561/can-a-timed-azure-function-run-multiple-instances.html) where the user reported the similar issue that the Azure Timer Triggered Functions running multiple instances at the same time and fixed the issue.